# Is it possible to get Windows 7 "Libraries" functionality on a Mac?

Tags: windows-7, windows, mac

Smart Folders are fantastic, but I would really like to replicate the Windows 7 "Libraries" functionality on my Mac. Is it possible? For example, most of my movies are stored on an external drive so they do not appear in the "Movies" folder unless I create an alias. The problem with an alias is it is one extra click to access my movies. It would be great if I could just automatically include all of the files and folders within my external drive's "Movies" folder.

Comment: One way is to create a Smart Folder called *Movies* that reads each one of your movies folders.

Comment: @fideli: That should be posted as an answer.

Comment: @surfasb: I am half-expecting Joshua to respond with a reason why this solution wouldn't work for him, given that he did mention Smart Folders in his question. Indeed, if this is the answer he's looking for, I'll gladly post it.

Comment: Yeah, I wish Libraries would allow you to add **saved search results**.  Would totally rock my socks.

Comment: @surfasb Unfortunately that doesn't accomplish what I want. It's close, but not quite. I would like the actual "Movies" folder to function as a Smart Folder. I could always place a Smart Folder inside of the static "Movies" folder, but that would add an extra click. I could always keep a Smart Folder in my favorites, but that adds additional clutter (plus I like knowing all of my movies can be accessed from the "Movies" folder).